# Where do I put a text file when using command line or Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, text-files

I am working on a project for school in which the user must input the name of a text file (QuizScores.txt in this case). Then I must validate that it exists or not. I have this part figured out. However when I was using Eclipse it couldn't find the file. I decided to try just using a command line but I'm not sure where to put my text file so that it will find it. I'm supposed to have the text file in a place where the user only needs to type in the name to find it. Thank you very much.

Here is my code:

```
    public static String fileValid(Scanner s, String fileName, String validateFile, boolean valid) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    do
    {
        valid = false;
        System.out.println("Enter name of quiz file (i.e. QuizScores.txt): ");
        fileName = s.nextLine();
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner (new File(fileName));

        if (!inFile.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("Error! File does not exist");
        }
        else
        {
        valid = true;   
        }
    }while(valid == false);
    return fileName;
}
```

Comment: At least post your code. If in the code you open the file by name, you need to put the file in the same directory you are running the .class binary file.
And also, you can just google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the file in the Eclipse project's folder. You can find out the full path by right clicking the project in Eclipse's Package Explorer, and then going to Properties, and choosing Resource tab. Assuming you have a default workspace set up, it'll be something like `C:\Users\<UserName>\workspace\MyProject` in Windows. If you put in any file here, you will be able to read it in your program.

Edit:
To try it for yourself, try running this code in a program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File f = new File("QuizScores.txt");
        f.createNewFile();
}
```

Then find out where the file is created. It will be in the folder I mentioned in my answer before.

Comment: When you are running your code from eclipse, and if the user enters QuizScores.txt, then your code will try to find it in the directory I specified in my answer. If you compile it into a runnable jar and run it using the command lin, then it'll look for the file in the same directory that the jar is put into.
Did you follow my answer?

Comment: Yes. I understand now. I fixed a few things and it's working properly now. Thank you very much.